# For loop causes Scanner to read another line

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm attempting to do the J3 Question of CCC 2019 and my code works for the most part, other than the fact that my for loop causes Scanner to read an extra line before reading the last line. You can find the exact problem here: https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc19j3

Expected Input:

```
4
+++===!!!!
777777......TTTTTTTTTTTT
(AABBC)
3.1415555
```

Expected output:

```
3 + 3 = 4 !
6 7 6 . 12 T
1 ( 2 A 2 B 1 C 1 )
1 3 1 . 1 1 1 4 1 1 4 5
```

My output:

```
3 + 3 = 4 ! 
6 7 6 . 12 T 
1 ( 2 A 2 B 1 C 1 ) 
"Scanner waits for another line here"
"If I press enter, it then spits out the last line."

1 3 1 . 1 1 1 4 1 1 4 5
```

I can't seem to find the problem and I have tried making the for loop into a method and then accepting four different inputs of Scanner (str0, str1, etc) for each input and it still reads another line. I addded sc.nextLine() after sc.nextInt() to make sure that Scanner reads the next line of input and the space next to the int. I tried omitting the last line of input, but then it just reads another line before the last line. So it seems that this problem is constrained to only the last line and not the specific input.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 1;
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++){
                if (j != str.length() - 1 && str.charAt(j) == str.charAt(j+1)){
                    counter++;
                }else{
                    System.out.print(counter + " " + str.charAt(j) + " ");
                    counter = 1;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you provide the test input to your program? Which platform are you testing on?

Comment: I'm testing on IntelliJ but the actual CCC problem with sample inputs can be found on DMOJ, the link that I put. Also I just pasted the input in. If I put the input manually one line at a time, while pressing enter between each line, my code works without any hiccups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're having a line ending problem.

`Scanner.nextLine()` will read a line *plus a line separator* from the input, then discard the line separator and *then* return the actual content of the line it read.

A line separator can be an LF character (`'\n'`) or a CR character (`'\r'`), or a CR character *followed by* a LF character, or one of several rarely used single-character Unicode line endings. This variety of separators reflects historical variation in how various operating systems represent text files. The `Scanner` tries to be helpful by accepting all of the possibilities no matter which platform it happens to be running on.

The behavior you observe can be explained if we assume that when you paste your test data, somehow the interaction between the program you paste **from** and the console that you're pasting **into** leads your program to be given lines that end with a single CR each. Then `Scanner.nextLine()` needs to see whether the *next* character it's given is an LF -- because if it is, then it should eat that too, as part of the line ending. And thus it will only return after it gets another character to look at.

On the other hand, when you type the input manually, your enter key probably produces either an LF or a CR-LF combination. Either of these will make `nextLine()` happy as soon as it sees the line ending itself.

You should be able to test this hypothesis if you *paste* the lines one by one. Then you would probably see that the translation of the first line comes only after you've pasted the second, and so forth.

**You probably won't need to worry about this** for the purpose of getting a programming challenge auto-judged. The judging system will not be *pasting* the test input into your program, but will probably *pipe* it, which means that your program gets to see all of the input up to the end-of-file indication at the end before it is expected to produce input. In that environment it should work fine.

Comment: Ok, I will test this later today. Yes it works, that makes a lot of sense now.